# How to use if else condition inside react object

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me an alternative to use if.. else.. condition inside a react object

```
const background = {
    color: {
      if ( this.props.status == 'broker') {
        background : '#FFFFFF'
      } esle {
        background : 'green'
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use binary operators: `-5 || '' // -5 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to evaluate it all inline. Nested ternary statements can get pretty ugly. You can just make a function and pass that result in:

```
function bgColor(status) {
  if (status === 'broker') {
    return { background: '#fff' }
  }

  if (status === 'whatever' {
    // return ...
  }

  // whatever else
}

const background = {
  color: bgColor(this.props.status)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary:

```
const background = {
    color: this.props.status === 'broker' ? '#ffffff' : 'green'
}
```

This could get limiting and/or hard to read if you want more conditions, so you could also make it function, but you'll just have to be careful of how/where you invoke it:

```
const background = {
    color: function() {
      let color

      if(this.props.status === 'broker') {
        color = '#ffffff'
      } else {
        color = 'green'
      }

      return color
    }
}
```

Comment: if i want to use more than 2 conditions then?

Comment: @radjeep nested ternarys ?

Comment: @RajdeepRatan I edited my answer. You can use nested ternaries like Jonas w suggested, but if those get hard to read, you can make your property a function.

Comment: @RajdeepRatan a nested ternary is not react specific. I would suggested looking up "nested ternaries in JavaScript" or something on google and reading about them.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by M0meni helped me-- but I still got an error of "objects not valid as react child". So i changed the solution a little bit and got it to work. Instead of return { background: '#fff' }
I used
return { '#fff' }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).